# How to enter success function of Ajax call?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, node.js

```
$.ajax({
          url: '/upload', 
          type: 'POST',
          data:formData,
          processData:false,
          contentType:false,
          error: function(jXhr, status){
              console.log('error: '+status);  
          },
          success: function(data){
              console.log('upload successful: '+data);
          }
      })
```

Hey, I am writing an app to find out the file size of a file the user uploads, and I want to do that by logging out the statement, data.size in the success function of the ajax call above. I know the ajax call is successful because in the server.js file below, the post request gets fired on the ajax calls return. But, the ajax call doesn't seem to enter the success method because no statements are being logged from it, but no errors are being returned from the ajax call either. How do I fix this?

**Note:** I know there have been other questions regarding the same issue, and I have tried implementing the solutions given there, but it doesn't seem to be working

```
var express = require('express');
var formidable = require('formidable');
var multer = require('multer');
var path = require('path');
var upload = multer({dest: './uploads'});
var fs = require('fs');

var app = express();

var PORT = 8080;

app.use(express.static(__dirname+'/views'));

app.set('views', './views');

app.set('view engine', 'jade');

app.get('/', function(req, res){
   res.render('index.jade'); 
});

app.post('/upload', upload.single('Upload'), function(req, res){
  // create an incoming form object
  var form = new formidable.IncomingForm();

  // store all uploads in the /uploads directory
  form.uploadDir = path.join(__dirname, '/uploads');

  // every time a file has been uploaded successfully,
  // rename it to it's orignal name
  form.on('file', function(field, file) {
    fs.rename(file.path, path.join(form.uploadDir, file.name));
  });

  // log any errors that occur
  form.on('error', function(err) {
    console.log('An error has occured: \n' + err);
  });

  // once all the files have been uploaded, send a response to the client
  form.on('end', function() {
    res.end('success');
  });

  // parse the incoming request containing the form data
  var data = form.parse(req);
  //console.log(data);

});

app.listen(PORT, function(){
    console.log('Express listening on port: '+PORT);
});
```

Comment: Any sort of error in console ? You never send `data.size` from server..

Comment: Don't set `processData` or `contentType`, unless you know what they do. Here's the documentation for [`$.ajax`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/).

Comment: @4castle - I'm setting it as false, because thats the version of the code I found online. 
I know processData is false to prevent jQuery from converting to string

Comment: use `res.send` instead of `res.end`